# Open file with Windows UWP application from command line

Tags: windows, command-line, uwp

I hope to open pdf file with a UWP application called Drawboard PDF. Both of the following commands launch the program normally.

```
start shell:AppsFolder\DRAWBOARD.DRAWBOARDPDF_gqcn7fs4pywxm!App
explorer.exe shell:AppsFolder\DRAWBOARD.DRAWBOARDPDF_gqcn7fs4pywxm!App
```

The next step is to pass pdf file as argument. However, simply adding the path after it doesn't work.

```
start shell:AppsFolder\DRAWBOARD.DRAWBOARDPDF_gqcn7fs4pywxm!App Example.pdf
```

What would be the correct command line that behaves just like right click a file and open it with a UWP application?

Comment: Even the command line is not supported for launching a UWP app. The way to launch a file into a UWP program is to use [LaunchFileAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchfileasync?view=winrt-22621).